# [PHP/AJAX]Project perfect on localhost but when uploaded to byethost,errors?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

I have a problem with installing [AJAX-CHAT](http://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/) **on on my host (Byethost)**
On localhost **(XAMPP)** it works perfectly, but when deployed to byethost with the new database connection,tables,and data configured properly,I can login but it fails to insert and show messages,and fails to display online users. The status circle is stuck on yellow.

```
STEPS TAKEN:
-Checked Connection (Good)
-Checked prerequisites (Good)
-Run /install.php (Good)
-Checked tables and proper database structure (Good)
-Run software on XAMPP (Good,no problems encountered)
-Overall Inspection (Good) 
(I have tried a lot of options. Trust me,I'm not being lazy)
```

Here is a link to my `/htdocs` folder. The database info is hidden for security,but it does connect properly

[htdocs folder (Uploaded to google drive)](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4Aem-ixyExxZUtnOVp2QVhJY0k&usp=sharing)

I use **byethost**. (Cannot post link,need 10 reputation)

```
**ERRORS:**
Wed, 21 Oct 2015 08:45:55 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/chat/lib/template/js/chat.jsWed, 21 Oct 2015 08:45:55 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/chat/lib/template/js/lang/en.jsWed, 21 Oct 2015 08:45:55 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/chat/lib/template/js/config.jsWed, 21 Oct 2015 08:45:55 -0500 AH00129: Attempt to serve directory: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/chat/lib/template/Wed, 21 Oct 2015 09:45:56 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/favicon.icoWed, 21 Oct 2015 09:46:06 -0500 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/js/chat.jsWed, 21 Oct 2015 09:46:06 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/favicon.icoWed, 21 Oct 2015 09:46:17 -0500 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/js/chat.jsWed, 21 Oct 2015 09:46:17 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/favicon.icoWed, 21 Oct 2015 09:46:17 -0500 AH00129: Attempt to serve directory: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/Wed, 21 Oct 2015 09:46:17 -0500 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/chat/js/chat.jsWed, 21 Oct 2015 10:46:24 -0500 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/chat/js/chat.jsWed, 21 Oct 2015 10:46:24 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/favicon.icoWed, 21 Oct 2015 15:45:33 -0500 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/js/chat.jsWed, 21 Oct 2015 15:45:33 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/favicon.icoWed, 21 Oct 2015 15:45:33 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/lightbox/css/lightbox.cssWed, 21 Oct 2015 15:45:33 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/css/jquery_ui.cssWed, 21 Oct 2015 15:45:33 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol2_6/byethost16.com/b16_16742662/htdocs/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to know what the errors you mention are. Also, have you checked whether the PHP (and anything else relevant) version on your host's server is the same (or at least recent enough) as your local?

Comment: Yes,they are the same. A error list has been added.

Comment: Sorry, where's the error list?

Comment: @TomJenkins,also visit http://thedarkden.byethost16.com/. Username: user Pass: user If you login,you can see what I am talking about

Comment: @Tom,error list is in the question above

Comment: The errors mention missing files. These files aren't in the htdocs folder you shared. I'd start by trying to fix those.

Comment: @Tom,fixed the files,but still does not work

Comment: @TomJenkins,used inspect elemt and found this:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden):                      http://thedarkden.byethost16.com/js/chat.js